# Does 2% milk make decent cheese?

Tags: milk, cheese-making

I ended up with a gallon (almost 4 L) of 2% milk that I don't really need. I was thinking of making it into some kind of fresh cheese (i.e., farmer cheese or panir or something) to extend its life a bit. Will this milk make decent cheese, or do you really need full fat milk for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost always use semi-skimmed (2%) for paneer, though if I'm making enough to buy milk specially I'll use full-fat for some or all of it.  There isn't much difference to texture or cooking properties (though I've never done a side-by-side comparison).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely can.

A couple of times I've had 1% or 2% milk left over after having guests, and not had any trouble turning it into ricotta or farmer's cheese.